# Is Flash Reactive Programming?

Tags: flash, reactive-programming

Can be Flash looked like a Reactive application?

For example http://elm-lang.org/ Elm language is Reactive, with Flash we may create the same applications as in Elm, but not in functional way, so is it reactive or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I have not used Flash, I can tell you what Reactive Programming is (also called Dataflow Programming). Let's say we have two equations:

```
c = a + b
d = c + e
```

If we start with a = 1, b = 2 and e = 3 then initially the value of 'c' is 1+2=3 and 'd' is 3+3=6. If the value of 'a' is later changed to 10 then the new value of 'c' is 10+2=12 and 'd' is 12+3=15.

Where reactive programming comes into the mix is that value of 'd' is automatically updated when the value of 'c' or 'e' is changed. All dataflow variables act this way throughout the whole program so you never have to worry about having old values. You might see a similarity with dataflow and spreadsheets. The value of a dataflow variable is the value of it at this moment, not some past time.

Dataflow variables "react" to changing data.

Another example would be setting a variable to the current time. Every time you access that variable it will return the current time, not the time it was first set.

All of this happens without the programmer explicitly updating the value of the variable, the dataflow system handles the updating.

A note on terminology... "Reactive Programming" is just the modern term for "Dataflow Programming" but they both are the same thing. You may have an easier time using "dataflow" as a search term.

Comment: In that case, If I got your explanation right, I would assume flash is not reactive. Also, thanks for the compreensive explanation.

Comment: Could you provide link to some real example of that kind Reactive (Dataflow) app? What about RxJava or Scala Akka - from the course 'Reactive programming in Scala' they considered as reactive, but you should explicitly set behavior eg onComplete, onSuccess, onError etc. Does it mean that Reactive term got wider?

Comment: I think it got wider, see [reactive manifesto](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/)

Comment: If you are referring to "Principles of Reactive Programming" on Coursera, then they are using Actors. Actors are a form of dataflow in that they react to incoming data. A simplistic explanation of the Actor model is that it is OOP where the objects have a single input to accept messages (as opposed to OOP where you call the methods directly). The actors are free to create other actors (and use them) or send messages to external actors that it knows of. This differs from the classic dataflow where the links between nodes are explicitly set by the programmer at design-time.

Comment: Some dataflow examples: my blog (http://DataflowBook.com), [NoFlow](http://noflojs.org/), [Dr. Dobb's article](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/dataflow-programming-handling-huge-data/231400148), [LabView](http://www.ni.com/gettingstarted/labviewbasics/dataflow.htm), [Mozart/Oz programming language](http://mozart.github.io/), [my intro video to dataflow](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFlT93wakVo)

Comment: @yons88 Excel sheet is a good real world example for reactive programming(i.e) consider we are summing up two cells value and assigning into another cell whenever we change one of the cells value the sum changes automatically

Answer (score 2):

Based off my understanding of reactive programming from skimming over the [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming) about it;

> For example, in an imperative programming setting, `a := b + c` would mean that `a` is being assigned the result of `b + c` in the instant the expression is evaluated. Later, the values of `b` and `c` can be changed with no effect on the value of `a`.
>
> In reactive programming, the value of `a` would be automatically updated based on the new values.

ActionScript 3 can be considered 'reactive' by implementing getters and setters, e.g.

```
public class Main
{
    public var b:int = 1;
    public var c:int = 1;

    public function get a():int
    {
        return b + c;
    }
}
```

Where the value `a` would differ depending on `b` and `c`.

```
var main:Main = new Main();
trace(main.a); // 2

main.b = 5;
trace(main.a); // 6
```